# Every time I drag the text field onto the screen it resizes to fit the entire screen. Any way I can resize it so that it is a small text box?

Tags: xcode, textfield

[image]

When I drag a textfield onto the screen it resizes to fit the entire screen.

I've worked with textfields before, so I am wondering why it is doing this now, and how to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing it directly on the ViewController not in a view. Add a view onto your ViewController and then add the textfield on to the view you just added.

[image: Photo Example]